# Meta data on site collection and/or site?

Tags: 2010

My customer have a SharePoint farm with several site collection (collaborative, portals, etc.).
I have to build a "page" that allow the customer to manage this site collection. By managing, I don't mean technical managing but functional managing.
The main use case is to allow the customer to "tag" sites, or to "attach" a site to a organizational entity.

Is there a way to add "metadata" on site ?
Or have I to create an hidden list with a single item that holds this data?

Nothing is fixed by now. Feel free to make any other suggestion.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing this in code, you can use the property bag to store objects.

Note that only SPWeb has an AllProperties property bag, so if you're doing this for Site Collection level, make sure you get RootWeb first, then set/get your AllProperties properties.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.allproperties.aspx

Note the example on that page has a few properties already set - you can add however many you want on top of this, though.

Answer (score 0):

A site directory could work too couldn't it? You can specify all the metadata fields you want, you can add site collections and subsites to the list and users can maintain the properties.  This would then allow you to slice and dice the data as needed.

Comment: probably, but I'll have to find a way to autopopulate this site directory...

Comment: and I'm not eased at using a disabled feature...